# How do I prevent a pre-set INPUT value from being changed?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, input

I have a form where some fields are completed by loading information from a database.  These fields can vary from one account to another.

When the form is submitted any database information will be sent along with new information entered in the form.

However, the user is able to change (on screen) the information entered from the database, and although these changes are not submitted (my $Xvariables from the database override the POSTed $variables), I would like them to revert the on-screen data back to the database value.

Here is an example of what I have at the moment, but it does not work ...

```
  <input type="text" name="firstname" size="25" tabindex="4" onchange="if($xfirstname<>'') this.value=$xfirstname" value="<?php echo $firstname;?>"/>
```

or better still, if there is a way, how can I make them unchangable if they have a value loaded from the database ?

Comment: Set `readonly` attribute to prevent the user from typing into them, or `disabled` to prevent them from being sent together with the rest of the form data altogether. (But be aware that this does not prevent a user from submitting any kind of data to your script in any way, so a server-side validation is mandatory.)

Comment: What about using just a simple text instead of <input> ?

Comment: Second @Ivan's suggestion, if you don't want any user input don't use an `input`.

Comment: some users will need to input - it all depends on what is loaded from the database

Comment: In a comment you say “some users will need to input”. You should specify such things in the question itself and specify what exactly should happen and under which conditions. Perhaps you just meant that a field should be readonly if it has a `value` attribute?

Comment: i did specify ... i explained that SOME field data is loaded, and this varies from one account to another ... this clearly implies that one user will be submitting different data to another and that ALL inputs thus need to be available to all users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep this:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" size="25" tabindex="4"
 value="<?php echo $firstname;?>"/>
```

Add this: Edit: Sorry did not see it has no ID on the input element use this:

```
<script>
if($('input[name="firstname"]').val().length > 0)
{
$('input[name="firstname"]').attr("disabled", true);
}
</script>
```

Result :http://jsfiddle.net/4wt9r/6/

But keep in mind anything on the client can be changed, your true filtering/authenticating must be done on the server.

Comment: I'd simplify the above to: [`$('input').prop('disabled', function(){ return this.value.length; });`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4wt9r/11/).

Comment: hmmmm, whilst i see both of these working on jsfiddle, they both fail on my site !!!! :(

Comment: the other thing with this, if i get it working, is, if someone enters a value that fails validation, will this prevent them from changing it ?

Comment: make sure you are including jquery library

Comment: omg, i am struggling as is it trying to learn html, javascript, php and css, and trying not to get them confused lol - will look into it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just place `readonly="readonly"` within the input `<>` tags or place `disabled="disabled"`

Example
`<input type="text" name="firstname" size="25" tabindex="4" onchange="if($xfirstname<>'') this.value=$xfirstname" value="<?php echo $firstname;?>" readonly="readonly" />`

Comment: But OP said it won't be submitted.